# fully customize theme or inherit from parent theme in magento2.0.1?

Tags: magento2, theme

My requirement is making one eCommerce site which totally different from magento luma/blank . I stuck with how to utilize theme in magento 2. In most of the tutorial inherit parent theme.

**which is the best way to achieve look and feel which totally different from Magento Luma/Blank and why ?**

the options are

1. Inherit parent theme(luma or blank)
2. Without inherit parent theme (fully customize)

Comment: So far, I have created themes without inheriting from a parent theme. According to Alan Kent "Magento/Blank" is just another theme. I generally work on projects where the front-end is totally different from luma/blank so it makes sense to avoid the bloat of those themes and start from scratch using my own LESS structure and positioning.

Comment: thanks it seems very reasonable, I need to work on your answer after that I will definitely come back to you.   +1 from me :-)

Answer (score 1):

From everything I've read so far, it appears to be best practice to inherit a parent theme (usually blank) and customise from there. That said, with the added complexity Magento 2 adds to the layout system, I have found it far easier to start from scratch and not extend from a parent theme, especially when it comes to modifying base structural content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd say do it from scratch, though I'm not very experienced with the system myself as of yet, so this may not be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start on a clean theme, use the 'Magento/blank' theme as your parent theme.

Take a look at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html & http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html.

Comment: already I read man! I have created one module and theme, theme extend to magento blank, struck with customize, really I need hints from expert like you :-) already some one handle this situation

Comment: Right. I think it's best to ask specific questions (in a separate question) as this question refers to which theme to use as a base. If you have specific customisation questions, I think best is to open a new question or search for already asked questions.