# Having new Magento 2 theme developed, is child theme best way?

Tags: magento2, theme

We are currently having a Magento 2 theme developed, they are starting in a few days. I know nothing about theme development so I am trying to make sure it is being done in the best way.

Should they develop the theme as a parent theme or a child theme of blank or luma?

Which is a more common way of doing it?

Since M2 is still fairly new and still working out different issues, we plan on keeping it updated with future releases as the bugs get corrected. Any advantages or disadvantages of creating a theme as a parent theme with these plans?

Looking for some experienced thoughts on this. Thanks for the input!

Comment: refer this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102622/fully-customize-theme-or-inherit-from-parent-theme-in-magento2-0-1

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 theme now more flexible and more management. But you can development it like 1x some of parts changed such as structure theme directory.
 You can do more with jquery components helps. And of course more technologies come with 
Official docs you can read in [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)

About theme basiclly you can start your theme with inherit theme blank(parent) or not inherit from any theme. It depends on your demand

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank

jquery library now included. You can use it anytime

> lib/web/jquery

Bootstrap not included, you have to port it to your theme. Almost asserts and resources of theme store in directory web inside your theme

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer really depends on the design that you're trying to implement.

If your designer used as an inspiration the Luma or the Blank theme, and made the design based on one of the parent themes, you should make your theme to inherit a parent theme. This will make more easier your develoment.

However if your theme doesn't have any similarities with Luma or Blank themes, you can start from scratch.

I hope this helps.